# implementing ontouchListener on emulator

Tags: android

I want to implement ontouchlistener but i don't have actual device to test it.I have already implemented onclicklistener.how can I implement both onclickLisrener and ontouhLisrener  with emulator.
thank you

Comment: they should both work in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Return values of onClick method and onTouch method set to false.

If you set "return true;", the Android stop to find event listeners.
So you want to enable two or more event listeners, you have to set return value false.